# Display active New Relic Alerts in AWS Managed Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, newrelic

I need to create an AWS managed Grafana dashboard to display active New Relic Alerts. I created a datasource for NewRelic. And then created a new panel and there chose NewRelic DataSource. I tried to write NRQL query, like "SELECT * FROM Alerts", "SELECT alertName, conditionName, startTime
FROM MetricAlertActive". But it's not working.

What is the correct NRQL query for displaying active New Relic Alerts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic incidents (which are triggered from alert conditions), are under a native eventType called "NrAiIncident" - To only fetch active-only alerts (those alerts that do not have a close event), this NRQL should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT uniqueCount(event) as 'total', latest(event) as 'state', latest(priority) as 'priority', latest(timestamp) as 'openTime' FROM NrAiIncident where event in ('open','close') facet title, policyName, conditionName limit max) where total=1 and state='open' limit max
```